# How do I return a substring from the right of a specified word/phrase in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I have a set of strings that contain a word, e.g., "delicious".

What is the best way to get the text to the right of "delicious", e.g.,

from: `"This is a delicious apple pie."`

return `" apple pie."`,

or from `"thisisadeliciousapplepie."`

return `"applepie."`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String objects contain a method [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=partition#str.partition) that's designed for exactly this use.

```
>>> s = 'this is a delicious apple pie'
>>> pre, target, post = s.partition('delicious')
>>> pre
'this is a '
>>> target
'delicious'
>>> post
' apple pie'
```

If the target substring isn't contained in the full string, the tuple returned will have empty strings in the 2nd and 3rd positions:

```
>>> s2 = 'this is an apple pie'
>>> s2.partition('delicious')
('this is an apple pie', '', '')
```

Comment: thanks for the most precise answer - appears to be exactly what partition was built for.

Comment: Great -- I should have noted that it's only available in versions >= 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that the variable contains a single occurence of "delicious", you can use `split`:

```
>>> s = "This is a delicious apple pie."
>>> s.split("delicious")[1]
' apple pie.'
```

But if the variable does not contain the word, you must prevent a possible `IndexError`!

```
>>> s = "This is an apple pie."
>>> s.split("delicious")[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a positive lookbehind in a regular expression:

```
(?<=delicious)(.*)
```

[Demo on Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/uD5pP6/1).

Comment: No need for a lookbehind; a garden-variety capture would work fine here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `find` and slicing:

```
thing = "This is a delicious apple pie."
search_word = "delicious"

print(thing[thing.find(search_word) + len(search_word):])
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you are not sure that the string contains a single instance of 'delicious', you can use `re`.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'A delicious apple pie. It is delicious beyond belief: deliciouspie!'
>>> [x[9:].strip() for x in re.findall(r'delicious\s*\w+', s)]
['apple', 'beyond', 'pie']
```